# Generating a separate page for each array item in Swift Xcode

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift5

when I use the first section of code I get two separate pages with both "Run 1" for page 1 and "Run 2" for page 2.

```
let pages: [String] = ["Run1","Run2"]
            
            for text in pages {
                let vc = TextViewController(with: text)
                myControllers.append(vc)
            }
```

However, when I update the array to bring back my arrays from my Structure file I get only one page with both run titles, i.e. "Run1Run 2"

```
let pages: [String] = [run.runTitle]
            
            for text in pages {
                let vc = TextViewController(with: text)
                myControllers.append(vc)
            }
```

I want separate pages for each run title like I got in the first section, what am I doing wrong?

Additional code:

```
import UIKit

var runs = [Run]()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
    // return the VC to be shown based on current position
        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            // find index in array
            guard let index = myControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), index > 0 else {
                return nil
            }
            let before = index - 1
            
            return myControllers[before]
        }
        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
                // find index in array
            guard let index = myControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController), index < (myControllers.count - 1) else {
                    return nil
                }
                let after = index + 1
                
                return myControllers[after]
        }
        
        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
         
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now(), execute: { self.presentPageVC()})
        }

        // create property of array objects
        var myControllers = [UIViewController]()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            if let savedRuns = Run.loadRuns() {
                runs = savedRuns
            }
            
            let pages: [String] = [run.runTitle]
            
            for text in pages {
                let vc = TextViewController(with: text)
                myControllers.append(vc)
            }
        }

        func presentPageVC() {
            guard let first = myControllers.first else {
                return
            }
            
            let vc = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .pageCurl, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
            
            // set up datasources
            vc.delegate = self
            vc.dataSource = self
            
            vc.setViewControllers([first], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
            
            present(vc, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `runTitle`?

Comment: If the only difference between these two code snippets is the first line, what do you see when you set a breakpoint for `run.runTitle`? `["Run1","Run2"]` or ["Run1Run2"]`?

Comment: Actually, yeah, like the other comment asks, give us some more about what `run.runTitle` is.

Comment: hey @GabrielPires and dfd runTitle is just a string, for example, "Run through City Centre". Hence I could put ["Run through City Centre","Run through Street X"]. In my stored array I have two array items "Run through City Centre" and "Run through Street X". However, when I try to bring these back using run.runTitle I would expect them to be separated but they are merged. 

I have var runs = [Run]() at the top of the file.

Comment: perhaps I need to create an loop inside 
let pages: [String] = ["","",""]

Where I pull out one array at a time? To stop it bringing all back? How would I do this?

Comment: hey @Jones, what do you mean "when I try to bring these back using run.runTitle". How do runTitle and your stored array communicate? From the 2nd block of code you have posted, the pages array only has one item, run.runTitle, not two. If you could post a bit more code, I could probably help more

Comment: @GabrielPires thank you I will edit the question and add the code as I exceed the character limit here

Comment: @GabrielPires I have just added more code, initially I am testing bringing back the title but later will bring back a date too from the stored data and other things. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Jones thanks for adding the additional code. One bit of confusion.... on the line `let pages: [String] = [run.runTitle]`. Where does `run` come from? I dont see a variable for that anywhere. I think you might want to be accessing `runs` or `savedRuns`. 
In that case, you may try `let pages: [String] = runs.map({$0.runTitle})`.  Lemme know if that works! If not, how does the Run class look?

Comment: @GabrielPires yes it worked, thank you so much ☺️ if I want to bring back an additional item how can I do that? I did try the below but it didn't work.

let pag: [String] = runs.map({$0.runTitle})
            let page: [String] = runs.map({($0.runNotes ?? "Empty")})
            let pages: [String] = pag + page
            
            for text in pages {
                let vc = TextViewController(with: text)
                myControllers.append(vc)
            }

Comment: @Jones :) no problem. Glad it worked! It was getting a little messy typing in the comments. Lemme know if my answer helps answer your question about returning additional items. I am not sure I am interpreting your second question correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let pages: [String] = [run.runTitle]` will only return an array with a single string.

You have `savedRuns` or `run` which is an array of Run objects.

You need to iterate through those array of Run objects and get the information from there.

For example, if you want to get an array of run titles, you can use the map method to help ([documentation on map](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map))

```
let pages: [String] = runs.map({$0.runTitle})
```

That will return an array of strings. It basically goes through the runs array and returns an array of each run.runTitle.

That is the same thing as this:

```
var pages: [String] = []
for run in runs {
    pages.append(run.runTitle)
}
```

---

Now, if you want to get back multiple items, you can do something like this:

```
let pages: [String] = runs.map({$0.runTitle + $0.runNotes})

or

var pages: [String] = []
for run in runs {
    pages.append(run.runTitle + run.runNotes)
}
```